# How to put several pictures on the same line in media object with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote the following HTML page :

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-body">
                Some text, some text, some text, some text
            </div>
            <div class="media-right">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                    Edit
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                    Delete
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is :

[image: output of HTML sample]

Is there a way to obtain the edit and delete button on the same line ? The media div is not mandatory. I just use it as a trick to put something on the left and something else on the right.

EDIT :

I changed line 14 according the answer :

The results is :

[image]

The buttons are now on the same line, but not on the same line as the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? If you are using bootstrap why not make use of the bootstrap grid? [**Here**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) you can read more about bootstrap grid.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Some text</span>
    <span>Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I do just not know that possibility. I have used bootstrap since one week :).

Answer (score 1):

Add   display: inline-block;

```
          <div class="media-right" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                Edit
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                Delete
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but buttons and text are not on the same line.